# The spectators SET UP a howl of protest

Tags: word-meaning, phrases

I know the meaning of the phrase verb *set up* in this context. But what does *set* and *up* mean separately here? In other word, I want to figure out the inner logic of this phrase. It would be great to show me the corresponding explanations in a dictionary, thanks in advance.

Comment: Few such phrases can be taken apart to discover their inner logic. They are more likely just to come to pieces.

Comment: Are you sure you heard that correctly? The usual phrase would be "The spectators **sent** up a howl ..."

Comment: @Peter Jennings This is an example sentence in my dictionary. You can find it in this [web](https://www.englishforums.com/English/SetUp/ggddx/post.htm): _6. transitive verb produce loud sound: ..._. Another use case is in Animal Farm Chapter II: _But at this moment the three cows, who had seemed uneasy for some time past, **set up** a loud lowing._

Comment: One of the definitions of **set up** given by Oxford Languages is _Begin making a loud sound. - 
"a colony of monkeys had set up a racket in the canopy"_

Comment: @Kate Bunting Well, I know the meaning of the whole phrase. I want to know the meaning of _set_ and _up_ separately in this phrase, thanks.

Comment: You just have to accept that it's a phrasal verb. I suppose the original meaning of _build, put in place_ extended to mean _start [something] going_.

Comment: @Kate Bunting _Set_ means _start_ as in **set to work** and _up_ means _going/happening_ as in **what's up**, am I right?

Comment: @Kate Bunting Or may be _set_ means _to cause something or someone to be in the stated condition or situation_. [set verb (CONDITION)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/set)

Comment: I don't know - your guess is as good as mine.

Answer (score 1):

*Set up X* is an example of a phrasal verb.

> The spectators SET UP a howl of protest

This is a not-too-common meaning of *set up* as described [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=to%20set%20up&rlz=1C1CHZN_enUS987US987&oq=to%20set%20up&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i512l6j69i60.2288j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8): "begin making a loud sound."

[Etymonline.com](https://www.etymonline.com/word/set) shows that the etymology of this word is all over the place - root words had meanings related to *sit*, meanings related to *sect*, and pertinent to this example: a meaning related to "cause/make to do".

Modern use of *set* is all over the place too.

As far as why *up* - while there's a logical connection between base and particle for many phrasal verbs, there isn't for all of them - e.g. what does the *out* in *carry out*--in the sense of "perform orders"--mean?  Why is the word *come* used in the phrasal verb *come apart*, when *come* means subject and a target move closer together?  Why does *make up X* mean to create a fake X?

Logic only takes you so far with English, there's numerous dead ends.

Answer (score 0):

When *up* is used in a phrasal verb, it usually carries one of these basic meanings:

- completion (finish up, eat up, write up, wrap up);
- upward movement (pick up, lift up);
- upright position, maintaining or strengthening it (prop up, shore up);
- increase, improvement (pep up, jazz up)

In your sentence, it has a meaning of completion. They arranged it, and they started it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and what does _set_ mean?

Comment: **Up** phrases also have a tendency to lower the tone, as in **shut** and ....... No, better I leave it there.

Comment: @preachers I think "set" here means "arrange, prepare", and then "up" completes/starts it (what was prepared)

Comment: "Set up" in this context suggests starting rather than finishing. Although I guess you can finish starting something.